# my code only prints the last value of the array

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, push

I made a variable and added new values with the push attribute but when the for-loop calls it one-by-one it only prints the last value(name) that is "Pranav". Can you help me to know how to fix it and print all the values one-by-one.

```
function tryme() {
    var names = new Array();
    names.push("Bhavesh", "Ajay", "Rahul", "Vinod", "Bobby", "Pranav");
    var tryit = document.getElementById("tryit");
    for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        tryit.innerHTML = "The values are " + names[i] + " . <br>"
    };
};
```

Comment: You are replacing the entire HTML everytime inside your `for` loop. Try appending it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are replacing the value of the `innerHTML` property each time through the loop.  You probably mean to append instead of replace. So...

Change this:

```
tryit.innerHTML = "The values are " + names[i] + " . <br>"
```

to this:

```
tryit.innerHTML += "The values are " + names[i] + " . <br>"
```

Comment: so the += will do the work of appending the names each time through the loop ?

Comment: @BhaveshParvatkar that's exactly how it works. It's equivalent to `tryit.innerHTML = tryit.innerHTML + "The values are " + names[i] + " . <br>";`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that on this line, you're setting the innerHTML equal to a single name, so it just gets overwritten each time:

```
tryit.innerHTML = "The values are " + names[i] + " . <br>"
```

Try changing it to append instead, or something similar:

```
tryit.innerHTML += "The values are " + names[i] + " . <br>"
```

Comment: '+=' is short for  'tryit.innerHTML = tryit.innerHTML + "The values are " + names[i] + " . <br>" '.                                                                                    
So whatever the current value of 'tryit.innerHTML' was, the new values are appended to it or added to it instead of replacing it.

Answer (score -1):

When used on strings, the `+` operator is called the `concatenation` operator.
`+=` thus, will mean to take append on previous value.

```
function tryme() {
var names = new Array();
names.push("Bhavesh","Ajay","Rahul","Vinod","Bobby","Pranav");
var tryit = document.getElementById("tryit");
tryit.innerHTML += "The values are<br>";
for (i=0;i<names.length;i++) {
   tryit.innerHTML += names[i] + "<br>"
};
}; 
tryme();
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/68Lk1u75/1/)